# Is disposing this object, enough? or do i need to do more?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, sha2

I have this code :-

```
using (System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256 sha2 = 
    new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed())
{ .. }
```

Do I need to put this line of code, just BEFORE I leave that dispose scope .. or does the dispose 'call' that already.

```
sha2.Clear();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since AFAIK the Clear() method just calls Dispose, the using block should be enough to ensure that the resources used are released.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO if calling Dispose() is not enough to dispose off an object then either there is a serious bug in the code or a serious flaw in the design. So don't worry about taking any additional steps in your own code!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look using Reflector, you'll see that `Clear` just calls `Dispose`, so there's no need to call `Clear` in your example.

Many of the framework classes offer a `Close`/`Clear`/Whatever cover for `Dispose` to make the usage a little more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

And a generic helpful hint - don't forget at that the source for all this stuff is available nowadays - it often helps me answer this sort of question, without having to guess or infer.

This is a good place to start: http://www.codeplex.com/NetMassDownloader

Comment: Well, you could look into the code just like you do with .NET Reflector. Given, that the source for system.security are yet part of the sources being published (I'm not sure).

Comment: Not sure why the swearing is in order, even abbreviated.  What it has to do with your question is that it's the kind of question that could be answered by looking at the source.  Had you been the type of person who wanted to learn about things, that might have been useful.  Sorry to have misread you

Answer (score -2):

Dispose() is good enough.

I am not sure how .NET works. But addition function call or "set null" will degrade the performance in Java.

The CLR/Java VM will(and must) able to cleanup all dereferenced managed object from "roots" in the next garbage collection.

PS.
Dispose() does cleanup "unmanaged" resources, to improve the GC performance as it don't wait for the Finallizer thread to complete.