# Will calling close() on my WCF service release all resources?

Tags: c#, wcf, garbage-collection

Will calling close on my WCF service kill all resources or set them up for GC or should I set it to null also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, WCF proxies are `IDisposable`, so you can *kind of* use `using`:

```
using(var proxy = new MyProxy()) { // see below - not quite enough
   // use proxy
}
```

**Unfortunately**, WCF also has a buggy `Dispose()` implementation that regularly throws exceptions. However, [here's a really cool trick](http://www.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Indisposable+-+WCF+Gotcha+1.aspx) to get it to work correctly. I also blogged about this [myself](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html), but I think the first link is a lot better.

So: use `IDisposable` and `using`, but use it with caution (in this case).

Setting a field *usually* makes no difference. There are a few edge-cases (such as variables captured by multiple delegates, static fields, long-life objects, etc), but in general leave it alone. In particular, do *not* do this, as this can theoretically *extend* the life:

```
if(field != null) field = null; // BAD
```

Comment: It sounds like OP is talking about a service, not a client, so I don't know that much of this is directly relavent (but is useful to know about WCF design choices with regards to Close/Dispose/Abort).

Answer (score 3):

This is not so much a WCF question as a .NET question; see also

[Setting Objects to Null/Nothing after use in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785/setting-objects-to-null-nothing-after-use-in-dot-net)

[Is disposing this object, enough? or do i need to do more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328743/is-disposing-this-object-enough-or-do-i-need-to-do-more)

[In the Dispose(bool) method implementation, Shouldn't one set members to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456551/in-the-disposebool-method-implementation-shouldnt-one-set-members-to-null)

Comment: Actually, it is - with WCF you **do** need to do more, due to the buggy Dispose() implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set a variable to null if it's going to be reachable for a long time afterwards. Say, a field on a long-lived object, or a static field. This holds in general, not just for WCF.